Wait the end of a Tkinter.bind() in Python
I have a little issue, I want to wait the end of a tkinter.bind() function before executing the next function/instruction in my script. How can I do that? Or, there is an other way to get realtime key input with Tkinter?
I try the bind, but it don't works like I want so :/

That's how Tkinter works already - until your handler function returns, the mainloop cannot process any further events.  You're going to need to supply a [mcve].

tkinter uses event driven programming. Basically the whole point is that it runs your functions only based on user input. There is no built in option for it to wait for an user interaction in the middle of a function. It can be hard when you are starting out with tkinter but it's a good way of programming GUIs

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
